# Get specific membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

**Is there a way to obtain a specific membership provider?**

When you make calls to the static [`Membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) methods they query whatever provider you have configured as the `defaultProvider`. Is it possible to get a reference to a specific provider that is configured in your web.config and query against only that provider?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you have multiple providers configured in your web.config, you can look them up by name.

```
MembershipProvider membershipProvider = Membership.Providers["foo"];
```

Comment: Ace. I think I suffer from API Blindness!