# Multi Tenant Environment - Multiple Membership providers, 1 DB per Tenant, One Single Application

Tags: azure, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database, multi-tenant

I've searched SO and could't find anything that matched my scenario...

Multi Tenant Environment - Multiple Membership providers, 1 DB per Tenant, One Single Application on Azure...

Question is quite straightforward:

Can Asp.net membership provider be configured like this? Any clues on how?

Now you guys know the question, lets head to the details...

This stack is supposed to run on Azure, with SQL Azure for persistent data, and ASP.net membership, MVC4, EF5, and some eye candy stuff...

The challenge consists in:

1. Create a multi-tenant environment running a single App in Azure (worker roles and web roles, but NOT tenant-specific or oriented);
2. One to One isolation of databases (one database per tenant);
3. One Asp.net Membership running in each database, in order to authenticate and authorize the users created by each tenant;
4. One main database, holding shared data and a main Asp.net Membership, where only admin users (main site admins and tenant admins) login...

Important to say that all databases have exactly the same structure, except for the main one...

Don't know if helps, but the stack also includes MVC4, EF5 (DB First approach);

Actually, I was considering to use the MVC route mechanism to collect tenant identification, and then setting up a specific Db Context, where all operations should apply;

Any ideas?

Comment: In order to add a little bit of extra details... Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466542/asp-net-membership-model-for-multiple-company-accounts-each-with-multiple-users) thread just before posting mine. I'm not comfortable at all to implement n tenants in single asp.net membership provider, no matter what... Risky to the bones...

Comment: For future reference... Just fond [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707529/get-specific-membership-provider) thread. Not perfect, but it's a step closer to a solution. The real problem is that it requires you to set EVERY new tenant into the web.config file. Oh, if such settings could dynamically pop from a datasource... Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the asp.net membership is not suitable for the multi-tenant environment as it does not support the concept of tenant identifier for identifying the membership and role details for a given user. either you can opt to go with a custom membership provider or use the federated or SSO and have a mapping of the applicatoin roles to that of the SSO Roles that the user brings in when he uses the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure the the ASP.NET membership database connection string at runtime.  [This thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/997608/2209437.aspx) has a few options including a custom membership provider or changing the value early on in the request lifecycle via Global.asax.cs.